# How get info about a method from bytecode?

Tags: java, bytecode, javassist

I would like discover which object are created inside the method and the name of the variable 
related from bytecode? I can I discover it?
I tried unsuccsefull using javassist. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Use javap to disassemble the program. Take a look here for more info: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javap.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I want discover it from my software. I thought to use the javassist library but I'm getting in a lot of trouble. I'm investigating the bytecode instruction by instructions and is not so easy.

Answer (score 1):

[ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) is the best choice. It is fast and has simple API and detailed [User Guide](http://download.forge.objectweb.org/asm/asm-guide.pdf). But you need to know [JVM bytecode instructions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Instructions.doc.html) to some extent.

Comment: Thank for your help.  don't know ASM, usually I've use javassist. I'll give a look at ASM but the time is never enough. It's strange doesn't exist already a library to get this information. I'll be the first one to build it :-) Any contributors?